# Can you set multiple column names as a macro in SQL to query against?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can you set multiple column names from a SQL table as a macro in SQL to query against?

For example I have multiple columns I am hitting against multiple times, can I use a macro or some type of reference to identify them ONCE to avoid displaying them repetitively and cluttering up the code?

The current code works, I am just looking for a cleaner/streamlined option.

Current Code:

```
WHERE ('ABC') IN 
        ([CODE1],[CODE2],[CODE3],[CODE4],[CODE5],[CODE6],[CODE7],[CODE8]
        ,[CODE9],[CODE10],[CODE11],[CODE12],[CODE13],[CODE14],[CODE15]
        ,[CODE16],[CODE17],[CODE18],[CODE19],[CODE20],[CODE21],[CODE22]
        ,[CODE23],[CODE24],[CODE25]
    AND ('CFS') IN 
        ([CODE1],[CODE2],[CODE3],[CODE4],[CODE5],[CODE6],[CODE7],[CODE8]
        ,[CODE9],[CODE10],[CODE11],[CODE12],[CODE13],[CODE14],[CODE15]
        ,[CODE16],[CODE17],[CODE18],[CODE19],[CODE20],[CODE21],[CODE22]
        ,[CODE23],[CODE24],[CODE25]
    ect...(20 more times)
```

Goal:

```
WHERE 'ABC' IN (&columnsmentionedabove)
   OR 'FGS' in (&columnsmentionedabove)
   OR 'g6s' in (&columnsmentionedabove)
etc.....
```

This is inherited code and just seems very clunky.

Thank you

Comment: You can create a table of the values and then use whatever `join` or `exists` or `in` clause that works.  IF I understand what you're after.

Comment: Are you looking for a way that enables you not to actually have to write the query?

Comment: There's not enough detail here for you to get any specific help. You will have a better experience here if you read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: The dreaded you don't know enough to ask an intelligent question response... ;)
I'll try and rephrase and add some detail.

Comment: I'm thinking there's a more graceful solution using `cross apply` and `( values ( CODE1 ), ( CODE2 ), ... ( CODE25 ) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbered columns like this are almost always a sign you should have an additional table. So if your existing table structure is like this:

```
Table1
Table1ID, OtherFields, Code1, Code2, Code3.... Code25
```

You really want something more like this:

```
Table1
Table1ID, OtherFields

Table1Codes
Table1ID, Code
```

Where each entry in `Table1` will have many entries in `Table1Codes`. Then you write `JOIN` statements to show the two sets side-by-side when needed.

```
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table1Codes tc1 ON tc.Table1ID = t.Table1ID AND tc.Code = 'ABC'
INNER JOIN Table1Codes tc2 ON tc.Table1ID = t.Table1ID AND tc.Code = 'CFS'
```

Or

```
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table1Codes tc1 ON tc.Table1ID = t.Table1ID AND tc.Code IN ('ABC','FGS','g6s')
```

Comment: Makes sense.  I can't cant split up the table but i can create a new table.  This seems much more efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the table's schema, as in often the case, you can `UNPIVOT` it. For example, assuming `CODE1`...`CODE25` come from `MyTable`, wrap the `UNPIVOT` operation inside a CTE:

```
;WITH
    cte AS 
    (
        SELECT      upvt.*
        FROM        MyTable
        UNPIVOT     (
                        CodeValue FOR CodeLabel IN ([CODE1], [CODE2], ..., [CODE25])
                    ) upvt
    )

SELECT      *
FROM        cte
WHERE       CodeValue IN ('ABC', 'DEF', ...)
```

The unpivot operation is not free. Make sure you filter as much as possible from `MyTable` before unpivoting the it.

Comment: This is intriguing and may work as well.  I will explore this more.  Thank you!